# fstream is failing to overwrite the contents of my text file

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, fstream

I was trying to write a program that uses fstream to read and write integers from a text file, but after the program is executed and exited from, the file does not change at all, and the contents remain the same.

Here's a short description of what my file is supposed to do:

1. This application reads a file, modifies its content, and writes the modification back to the same file.
2. The file includes 3 lines of integers. The first line indicates the number of integers on the third line. The second line indicates which integer on the third line has been selected (active).
3. The third line in the file lists all the integers (maximum of 10).
4. A menu that is constantly displayed on the screen. Right below the menu, the program displays all the integers in the third line of the file
5. The program also displays which integer is currently selected (active).
6. The user can select a menu item by pressing one of the extended keys from the menu
7. Pressing “Insert” will insert an integer before the selected integer and makes the newly inserted integer active. The integer is typed by the user. If the list is full, insertion will not be possible.
8. Pressing “Delete” deletes the active integer.
9. Pressing “Sort” sorts the list in ascending order. The active integer after the sort is same as the active integer before the sort.
10. Pressing “Select” selects the next integer in the list. If the last integer is selected, this option selects the first item in the list.
11. Pressing “Move right” moves the selected integer one position to the right. If the last integer is selected, moving right will not be possible.
12. Pressing “Move left” moves the selected integer one position to the left. If the first integer is selected, moving left will not be possible.
13. Pressing “Exit” ends the application.
14. The program saves the content of the file into an array, modifies the array, and writes back the content of the array into the file.

[My program:]

```
//Description: Grade averages
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>//allows file streams
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
void menu();//declaration of the menu funtion
int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int next = 0;
    fstream f_stream;//declares the stream that allows the program to read/write from the file
    f_stream.open("base.txt");//opens the file
    if (f_stream.fail())//checks if the file is present
    {
        cout << "base.txt is missing. program cannot run :(" << endl;//displays an error if the file can't be found
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "input stream successfully opened" << endl;//confirms that the file is available
    int ch =0;
    int values[12];//declares the array that will store the file's integers
    do
    {
        menu();//displays a menu for inputs
        while (!f_stream.eof())//runs until the end of the file is reached
        {
            f_stream >> next;//grabs values from the file
            values[num] = next;//assigns a file input to an expression in the array
            num++;//this keeps tally of the number of items in the file
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Here is the list of numbers on the third line: " << endl << endl;
        for (int t = 2; t < num; t++)//this displays the values on the third line
        {
            cout << values[t] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
        int num_of_integers = num - 2;//this is the number of files in the 3rd line. the first and second line numbers are subtracted
        int active  = values[1];//the integer from the second line displays the number that is active
        int activenumber = values[active];//grabs the active number
        cout << "Number of integers: " << values[0] << endl;
        cout << "Current active integer: " << activenumber << endl;

        ch=getch();//grabs keyboard input
        if (ch == 0||ch == 224)//
            ch=getch();//only allows special keys to be used
        int newactivenumber;
        int lastorder = num - 1;//this is the last element in the array
        if (ch == 82)//if the "insert" key is pressed
        {
            if (num == 12)//if the maximum number of integers is present in the file
            {
                cout << "Cannot insert an integer before " << activenumber << endl << "Please delete an integer before inserting" << endl;
            }
            else if (values[active] == values[3])//if the active integer is the very first number on the second line
            {
                cout << "Please enter an integer to insert at the end of the number line" << endl;
                cin >> values[num-1];
            }
            else//inserts a number before the active integer
            {
                cout << "Please enter an integer to insert before " << activenumber << endl;
                int previous = active - 1;
                cin >> values[previous];
            }
        }
        else if (ch == 83)//if the "delete" key is pressed
        {
            cout << values[active] << " was deleted." << endl;
            int temp, temp1;
            for (int p = active; p<(lastorder);p++)//shifts all values in the array to the left
            {
                temp1 = p + 1;
                values[p] = values[temp1];
            }
            int new_integers = num_of_integers - 1;
            values[0] = new_integers;//since a value was deleted, the new amount of integers is recorded
            num--;
        }
        else if (ch == 80)//if the "arrow down" key is pressed
        {
            if (values[1] == lastorder)//if the last number on the list is the active number, then the first number on the list will become the new active number
            {
                newactivenumber = 2;
                values[1] = newactivenumber;
            }
            else//the next number of the list will become the new  active number
            {
                newactivenumber = values[1] + 1;
                values[1] = newactivenumber;
            }
            cout << values[newactivenumber] << " is now selected" << endl;

        }
        else if (ch == 77)//if "arrow right" is pressed, the active number is shifter to the right
        {
            if (values[active] == values[num-1])//disallows shifting if the active number is the last number on the list
            {
                cout << "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that." << endl;

            }
            else
            {
                int temp;
                temp = values[active];
                int rightno = active + 1;
                values[active] = values[rightno];
                values[rightno] = temp;
                cout << "The active number has been moved 1 position right in the list" << endl;

            }
        }
        else if (ch == 60)//IF the F2 key is pressed, the array numbers are sorted from smallest to greatest
        {
            int i;
            int temporary = values[active];
            for(i=2;i<num;i++)
            {
                for(int j=2;j<num-i-1;j++)
                {
                    if(values[j]>values[j+1])
                    {
                        int temp = values[j];
                        values[j] = values[j+1];
                        values[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            //displaying result
            cout<<"Sorted list"<<endl;
            for(i=2;i<num;i++)
            {
                cout<<values[i] << endl;
            }
            for(i=2;i<num;i++)//this loop ensures that the active number remain the same, even after the sorting
            {
                if (values[i] == activenumber)
                {
                    values[1] = i;
                }
            }

        }
        else if (ch == 75)//if "arrow left" is pressed, it shifts active number to the left
        {
            if (values[active] == values[2])//
            {
                cout << "I'm sorry, Dave. I,'m afraid I can't do that." << endl;

            }
            else
            {
                int temp;
                temp = values[active];
                int leftno = active - 1;
                values[active] = values[leftno];
                values[leftno] = temp;
                cout << "The active number has been moved 1 position left in the list" << endl;

            }
        }
        else if (ch == 59)//terminates program if F1 is pressed
        {
            f_stream.close();
            cout << "streams successfully closed" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else//if an invalid key is pressed
        {
            cout << "Try again" << endl;

        }
        for (int out = 0; out < num; out++)//exports array values to the file
        {
            if (out == 0 || out == 1)
            {
                f_stream << values[out] << '\n';
            }
            else if (values[out]==0)
            {
                f_stream << "";
            }
            else if (out != num-1)
            {
                f_stream << values[out] << " ";
            }
            else
            {
                f_stream << values[out];
            }
        }
        system("PAUSE");
        system("CLS");
    }
    while (ch != 59);
    f_stream.close();
    cout << "streams successfully closed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
void menu()//self-explanatory
{
    cout<<"Menu:" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "1.Insert" << "Press the \"Insert\" key" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "2.Delete" << "Press the \"Delete\" key" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "3.Sort" << "Press the \"F2\" key:" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "4.Select" << "Press the \"Down Arrow\" key" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "5.Move Right" << "Press the \"Right Arrow\" key" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "6.Move Left" << "Press the \"Left Arrow\" key" << endl;
    cout << setiosflags(ios::left) <<  setw(14)<< "7.Exit"<< "Press the \"F1\" key" << endl;
}
```

[Base.txt]

```
10
9
-23 5 23 56 0 -32 3 9 11 66
```

Comment: "Here's a short description of what my file is supposed to do:"  ... really ?

Comment: You can open an fstream for input or output, not both.

Answer (score 0):

When using the fstream data type it's crucial to specify the type of file access. There's a number of ways to go about it in your code but the simplest to me seems to be:

```
fstream f_stream;
f_stream.open("base.txt", ios::in | ios:out)
```